# Removing all files from a folder with by searching for a string in unix

Tags: unix, shell

I'm working on a solaris box. How do I go about deleting all files in a folder, which have the word"Failure" in them ?

i'm trying something in the lines of the following, but it doesn't seem to remove anything.

```
rm -rf | find ./*.log -exec grep 'Failure' \;
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret correctly you don't require recursive searching, so something like:

```
rm -f `grep -m 1 'Failure' ./*.log | cut -d: -f1`
```

should work. If not, try:

```
rm -f `grep 'Failure' ./*.log | cut -d: -f1 | uniq`
```

Comment: I get an "grep: illegal option -- m" message. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name \*Failure\* -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: I'm trying the following, with no results :
find . -exec grep "Failure" -exec rm {} \;

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn that around. Use find to locate the files and then use the -exec option with the rm command.